# JavaScript Calculator Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm following along with the examples of a JavaScript book and have come across one of the examples not working as it should. It's supposed to prevent the html form from actually being submitted to calculate.php and instead use the JavaScript function calculate() to perform the calculations. Currently, it's submitting the form instead of using the JavaScript function. My code is exactly how it is in the book and I'm not sure why it's not working correctly.

Below is the code I'm using: calculator.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" lang="en">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="display">
        <p>Click To Show/Hide Calculator</p>
    </div>

    <form method="post" id="theForm" action="calculate.php">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Calculate</legend>
            <div>
                <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
                <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="1" min="1" required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="price">Price per Unit:</label>
                <input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="1.00" required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="tax">Tax Rate (%):</label>
                <input type="text" name="tax" id="tax" value="0.0" required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="discount">Discount:</label>
                <input type="text" name="discount" id="discount" value="0.00" required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="total">Total:</label>
                <input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="0.00">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Calculate" id="submit">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.1.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/shopping.js"></script>
</body>
```

And here is the JavaScript: shopping.js

```
function calculate() {
'use strict';
var total;
var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity');
var price = document.getElementById('price');
var tax = document.getElementById('tax');
var discount = document.getElementById('discount');
total = quantity * price;
tax /= 100;
tax++;
total *= tax;
total -= discount;
total = total.toFixed(2);
document.getElemenyById('total').value = total;
return false;
}

function init() {
'use strict';
var theForm = document.getElementById('theForm');
theForm.onsubmit = calculate;
}
window.onload = init;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#display").click(function(){
       $("#theForm").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: If that book really suggests that you mix jQuery calls with plain DOM manipulation like that, I'd find another book.

Comment: Anyway does *anything* happen? Have you tried adding `console.log()` messages to make sure the function is being called?  Have you checked the console for possible errors? The code you've got now needlessly imports the jQuery library twice, which won't hurt anything but it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form tag needs an onsubmit:

```
<form method="post" id="theForm" action="calculate.php" onsubmit="return calculate()">
```

Otherwise it doesn't know to run that function.

EDIT -------

Apologies, I missed that you had it already set. The problem is easier than that anyway. This:

document.getElemenyById('total').value = total;

should be

document.getElementById('total').value = total;

The Chrome javascript console can be very valuable to finding these sorts of typo issues:

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Comment: Apologies, I missed that. The problem is easier than that anyway. This:

document.getElemenyById('total').value = total;

should be 

document.getElementById('total').value = total;

Comment: Thanks Keith, I feel bad it was just a typo haha

Answer (score 0):

This function `document.getElementById` returns the element and not the value of the element. And for the reason you mentioned `jQuery`, you can use `$('#id')` instead, this will return the element as well, and you can use the `val()` method to get the value of the element as following:

```
var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
```